# Laravel Has Many Trough with multiple levels

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a very specific query that I don't know how to get in Eloquent

I have the following tables

`Orders`, `OrderInvoice`,`OrderPayment`

So each `Order` has many `OrderInvoices` and each `OrderInvoice` has many `OrderPayments`

Then I have the table `turns` which has many payments

So what I want is to get all the orders related to a specific turn

I know how to get all the invoices:

`$this->belongsToMany('OrderInvoice','orders_payments','turn_id','invoice_id');`

But I need the next level and get the Orders, 
How can I achieve that in eloquent?

Thank you so much!

**EDIT: Tables structure**

**Orders**
id

**OrderInvoice**
id
order_id

**OrderPayment**
id
invoice_id
turn_id

**Turns**
id

Comment: Show your tables, because your description is unclear - what does turn have to do with OrderInvoice and why it is in the `orders_payments` pivot table? And if it's `hasMany` then there is no pivot table at all..

Comment: Just edited the question with the tables and its relevant fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most straightforward:

```
// load related collections
$turn->load('invoices.orders');

// then
$turn->invoices; // collection of invoices, for each you can do this:
$turn->invoices->first()->orders; // collection of orders for an invoice
```

If you want to get single collection of orders for given `turn`, then you need this trick, which is the easiest way (no joins etc), but not the best in terms of performance for sure:

```
// store orders in a separate variable
$turn->load(['invoices.orders' => function ($q) use (&$orders) {
   $orders = $q->get()->unique();
}]);


// then
$orders; // single collection of all the orders related to the given turn

// also still accessible as usually:
$orders->invoices;
$orders->invoices->first()->orders;
```

Comment: I finally used this function, is there any better way for that? 
the (&$orders) thingie crashed...
```
public function orders(){
        //GSTODO: Improve this one for more performance
        $this->load('invoices.order');
        $orders = $this->invoices()->first()->order;
        foreach($this->invoices() as $invoice){
            $orders->merge($invoice->order);
        }
        return $orders;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `crashed`?

Comment: With this code http://pastebin.com/B67MkLc5 I get a syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting '{' error

Comment: Yeah, there was `use` missing in the closure. Check the edit.

Comment: I see, it seems to work :D however, when I try to add a ```->where()``` to the ```$orders``` I get that it is an undefined method :D

Comment: Well, it works, not only seems to :) `$orders` is already a collection, so you can't add `where` obviously. What you want to achieve with that?

Comment: What I want to achieve, is to filter the order by a field ```(date > 'a date')``` but not always, since sometimes I need them all

Comment: So just add that `where` before `get` in the closure and you're done.

Comment: And what if I return ```$q``` direclty? I mean ```$orders = $q``` this way can I work with that like if its just a belgonsToMany relationship?

Comment: Sure you can do that.

Comment: Thank you! it works like a charm! should I use the ```distinct``` to get don't get them repeated (like the ```unique``` you used?)